# How to create clickable link with GWT?

Tags: html, gwt

I want to make some clickable links with GWT. I'm not sure if this is the best practice for it. Basically I want something that similar like this if I would've written with html

`<a href="index.html" alt="">Link</a>`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [Hyperlink](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Hyperlink.html) if you want to "link to some place" in your app (meaning it fires a History change event).
Use an [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html) if you want to link to a site ouside of your app.

```
Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink("link to foo", "foo"); //text would be "link to foo", would change your url to yourSite.html#foo
Anchor anchor = new Anchor("Link to bar", "www.bar.com"); //text would be "link to bar", would redirect you to "www.bar.com"
```

Comment: A little clarification about `Hyperlink` - its main advantage/purpose over `Anchor` is that it fires [History](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) changes events (it might not have been clear from the "some place in your app" remark :)).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Igor. I changed it to make it clearer.