# How to add hyperlink as a cell value into flextable in GWT

Tags: gwt, hyperlink

I have a flextable in GWT and I want the values of the column 1 should be a hyper link. How to add these values. Thank you for your help.

Comment: show us what youve tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you'd like to know exactly, but to quote the [GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlexTable.html):

> A flexible table that creates cells on demand. It can be jagged (that
>   is, each row can contain a different number of cells) and individual
>   cells can be set to span multiple rows or columns.

To see an example of how to use it check [this](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwFlexTable) link.

To learn how to create a hyperlink to a page or an external site check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770664/how-to-create-clickable-link-with-gwt) thread.

In your case in order to add a hyperlink in the first column you should create a hyperlink and add it to the flex table using the setWidget(int row, int column, IsWidget widget)  method as follows:

```
Anchor link1 = new Anchor("Link page1", "www.mypage1.com");
Anchor link2 = new Anchor("Link page2", "www.mypage2.com");

flexTable.setWidget(0, 0, link1);//row 0, column 0
flexTable.setWidget(1, 0, link2);//row 1, column 0
```